# How to get a nice output-table for a GOLM using package "oglmx"?

Tags: stargazer, texreg

I run a generalized ordinal linear model with the package "oglmx" - so far so good. The model is specified as follows:

```
   scarce.cs.golm <- oglmx(as.factor(SCARCE) ~ region + wavet + sex + age.s + edu + income + urban + reli2 + 
                           GDPcapita_y.log  + fmlabfor_y.s +GPIter_y.s + trade_y.s + FDI_y.s + sap_y + 
                           polity + marxcom + patrstate1, data = wvsf,weights = weight1, link="probit",
                           constantMEAN = T, constantSD = T,threshparam = c(1.78,2.89))
```

Now, I would like to get the results in a nice output-table. Usually, I use either stargazer or htmlreg (from package "texreg"), but this does not work for oglmx. Not even screenreg works. The following error message comes up:

**unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"oglmx"’**

Does anyone know how to procede with the issue? Any help is highly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've just added oglmx class to texreg by writing an extract function. However, it is still not into the package since the Pull Request needs to be approved.

If you still need it urgently you can do this:

```
install.packages("devtools")
install_github("czucca/texreg", ref = "oglmx")
library(texreg)
```

and then use

```
htmlreg(scarce.cs.golm)
```

and it works!

Hope this helps,
C.